# relu activation function using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, activation-function, relu

Hi I want to implement a lambda function in python which gives me back x if x> 1 and 0 otherhwise (relu):

so I have smth. like:

```
p = [-1,0,2,4,-3,1]

relu_vals = lambda x: x if x>0 else 0 

print(relu_vals(p))
```

It is important to note that I want to pass the value of lambda to a function

but it fails....

Comment: looks very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32109319/1358308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply this function on every element of the list

```
list(map(relu_vals, p))
```

gives you

```
[0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1]
```

Also it's better to define the lambda function within `map` if you are not planning to use it again

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x if x > 0 else 0, p)))
```

Comment: But I want to pass the value to a variable like:  relu_vals = lambda... This fails...

Answer (score 2):

You program is right, but need some modification.

Try this,

```
>>> p = [-1,0,2,4,-3,1]     
>>> relu_vals = lambda x: x if x>0 else 0     
>>> [relu_vals(i) for i in p] 
[0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1]
```