# Manually perform predictions using the model weights and biases (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, matrix, neural-network

I'd like to manually predict data (regression task) using the model weights and biases in Keras (i.e., Z = f(WX+B), where Z is the output of a layer, W is the weight matrix, X is the input vector, and B is the bias vector).

My model architecture is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(207, input_dim = 173, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(207, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(207, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(240))
```

I'm also done with training the model.

I have already tried extracting the weights and biases using the following:

```
layer_num = 1
layer_weights = model.layers[layer_num-1].get_weights()[0]
layer_biases  = model.layers[layer_num-1].get_weights()[1]
```

where `layer_num` is the layer number (`layer_num` runs from 1 to 4 for my model). However, I can't figure out how to do the Z = f(WX+B) manually for my test set `x_test`.

Using this manual method, I'd like to compare its results and `model.predict`, as well as get the prediction computation time per instance/row of `x_test` (but I suppose I can figure out this last part on my own).

Edit 1: I mentioned that I can figure out the computation time per instance/row on my own, but if you could help me with this also, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dense layer, when you call the `get_weights` method, you will get a list, whose first element is the weight matrix `W` and second element is the bias `b`:

```py
W, b = dense_layer.get_weights()
```

Suppose you have a test data matrix `X` with shape `[batch, 173]`. Then you can write a code snippet like below to get all the weights and biases:

```py
Ws, bs = [], []
for layer in model.layers:
    W, b = layer.get_weights()
    Ws.append(W)
    bs.append(b)
```

With them at hand, we can define our function:

```py
def relu(x):
    return np.where(x >= 0, x, 0)


def identity(x):
    return x


def predict(Ws, bs, activations, X):
    Z = X
    for W, b, activation in zip(Ws, bs, activations):
        Z = Z @ W + b
        Z = activation(Z)
    return Z
```

Then you can use the `predict` function to manually predict for test `X`:

```
Y = predict(Ws, bs, (relu, relu, relu, identity), x_test)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the same answer as in `model.predict`. However, now, I can't seem to get the prediction/computation time for each row/instance. I am planning to use `start_time = time.time()` and `end_time = time.time()` then get the `elapsed_time = end_time - start_time` for each row/instance.
Would you know how to do this for your code?

Comment: Correction: *almost* the same answer. One predicted value is `6.3774832e-02` using the Keras `model.predict` while its counterpart using your method is `6.37749414e-02`. I suppose the discrepancy is negligible and the difference may be on how Keras implemented its prediction computation.

Comment: @RonaldCabaoig You can get the computation time for each instance by passing only one instance to the `predict` function and then record the time. For example, you can create a loop, where at each iteration a matrix of only one row (shape `[1, 173]`) is passed to the `predict` function. You can achieve that by `row = x_test[i].reshape(1, -1)`, and then you will be able to get the time by placing `start_time` and `end_time` around the line calling `predict(Ws, bs, activations, row)`.

Comment: This works! Really appreciate your help. One last question: I suppose calling the defined functions takes additional time (my goal is to get the fastest possible time of manual prediction per row). Is there a way to do the math per row without using the functions (i.e., using just a single equation by calling the input, weights, and biases at the same time)?

Comment: @RonaldCabaoig Yes, you can write the whole computation graph in a single line, but the single python line will still contain multiple calls to the numpy functions. Your model contains several layers and can only be computed sequentially. I think the time cost to run a single-line version will be roughly the same. If you want to run more efficiently, you may find a better implementation, such as a faster ReLU implementation using numpy (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109319/how-to-implement-the-relu-function-in-numpy)).

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sticking with your method.